# magento database repair tool : how it works?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I used the database repair tool as described in below link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

they said Only table charset was changed.

but my question is **how it actually works** with the corrupted database and reference database.

can I set the fresh database as a reference database?

Comment: It might be worth noting what is actually wrong with your database. Errors thrown? PHP errors? Magento Logs etc. I have used the DB tool and it is pretty basic for repairing mistakes that magento makes in the backend on its own. If you are doing any custom programming (calling soap, custom php) like I am, the DB repair tool is not going to be able to magically 'put your database back together'.

Comment: @CarComp so I can use the fresh database as a reference?